# Decoupled Github Oauth2 through a rails server from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am trying to do Github Oauth2 from my chrome extension but instead of using the  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow I am trying to do it through my server, so I do not have to put my client ID and Client Secret in the javascript of my chrome extension. The way I was planning to do this is my using an ajax call to my rails server

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/github-api/login-html',
  crossDomain: true,
}).done(function(response){
  debugger
  console.log("done")
}).fail(function(error) {
  debugger
  console.log( "error" );
}).always(function() {
  console.log( "always" );
});
```

then making the Oauth request from there to github for the sign in page:

```
def login_html
    @github_login_html = HTTParty.get('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=697d344740e266bf7a02&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/')
    bingind.pry
    render json: @github_login_html
end
```

and essentially forwarding this back to the chrome extension and presenting it to the user in a popup triggered by the chrome extension.

My problem is that the @github_login_html is exactly what i need it to be at the binding.pry in #login_html but when it gets back to the ajax request it triggers the .fail function and the response text is

```
"serverdatecontent-typetransfer-encodingconnectionstatuscontent-security-policypublic-key-pinscache-controlvaryx-ua-compatibleset-cookiex-request-idx-runtimex-github-request-idstrict-transport-securityx-content-type-optionsx-xss-protectionx-frame-optionsx-served-b"
```

but it has a status 200 and statusText "OK".

Not sure what is causing this or another way I could go about doing the Oauth that would keep my Client ID and Key hidden from users. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you solve a problem on your own, please post the solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question. We don't see that the question is solved from the list of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

The problem was I didn't realize I was trying to send a HTTParty object not a string so I had to do @github_login_html.to_s before I was able to send it.

However, it's still going to the fail function for no apparent reason so if anyone has any ideas on why that is happening I would love to hear them.